# Developing stronger kicks for soccer

Tags: sports, soccer

I wonder how can you train powerful kicks for soccer?

Would kicking a punching bag on the floor help? Would filling a soccer ball with cloth help?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that this is a skill rather than a 'strength' exercise. For instance if you got an olympic weightlifter to kick a football as far as they could, i can't imagine it would be any futher than your typical sunday league football player. Actually i'd say the average sunday league player has a better chance of kicking it farther.

Based on my own assumption that this is a skill, the only real way to improve is through repetition and mastery of technique. If you were to take the example of a professional kicker in Rugby or American Football, they spend a good portion of their training just kicking the ball.

Never really been one for football myself but i'd suggest looking up some training videos for kicking technique, or maybe some popular drills.

Just as a side note, the problem with the examples you gave is that they are "non-specific" to the skill you are trying to learn. Especially the punching bag example, This has very little similarity to actually kicking a football. You can't really have a follow through kicking a punching bag on the floor. As a result i would argue that this will have next to no carry-over to kicking a ball.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials to learn how to kick the ball properly. As the above answer mentioned it mainly comes from the technique and slowly increasing power with the technique. Soccer players do weight training for their leg and body for increasing overall endurance, stamina and so on. Power in legs does help only if you have a good technique.

you may not need much power if your technique is good.
Also, there are several kinds of kicks you could take 
Banana Kicks, Ping the ball, Knuckleball etc..

Try learning each technique and practice a lot doing more of it.